# Как зашифровывать письма с помощью exim?

Tags: email, smtp, tls, exim

Кто-нибудь использовал TLS при настройке почты на SMTP сервере EXIM?

Нужно, чтобы проходящая через EXIM почта шифровалась, уходя вовне.

Например, на внешний домен mail.ru почта зашифровывалась.

Можно ли так сделать, или есть какие-то другие варианты конфигурации?

Comment: Если вбить в поисковик «exim tls», там сразу же будет куча ссылок на эту тему, в том числе из [официальной документации exim](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-encrypted_smtp_connections_using_tlsssl.html#SECTclientTLS). Вас это чем-то не устроило?